# Two separate partitions on two columns

Tags: oracle, partitioning, oracle12c

In an Oracle table, there are going to be two columns,

```
Col_1 (date) and Col_2 (timestamp).
```

I wish to create partitions separately on those columns (not a single multi-columns partition).

I.e. not a single partition on `Col_1, Col_2` condition, but rather a separate partition on `Col_1`, and separate partition on `Col_2`.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually it is the same wether you create by `Col_1, Col_2` or `Col_1` and `Col_2`.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit why?

Comment: What is your intention for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it is possible with Oracle to have >1 partition on a table. Only Partition and subpartitions.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle partitions are always done by ROW, based on 1 or 2 columns as partition key. If you use 2 columns you have a composite partition key, aka. PARTITION and SUBPARTITION.

From that point it would not make any difference wether you have partition key `col_1` and `col_2` or `col_1 || col_2` - although it would be a **very bad idea** to concatenate date strings!

So, it is not possbile but a workaround could be to used Nested-Tables like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TS_TABLE_TYPE AS TABLE OF TIMESTAMP(3);

CREATE TABLE my_table (
    col_1 DATE,
    col_2 TS_TABLE_TYPE)
NESTED TABLE col_2 STORE AS NT_TS_TABLE_TYPE (TABLESPACE TABLESPACE_A)
TABLESPACE TABLESPACE_B;

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (col_1, col_2) 
   VALUES (SYSDATE, TS_TABLE_TYPE(SYSTIMESTAMP));
```

`col_1` would be stored in a different segment than `col_2`, thus they could be stored even on different file systems but logically it looks to be a single table.

However, I would consider this as a fairly bad workaround. Another also very fairly bad workaround would be using CLOB:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
    col_1 DATE, 
    col_2 CLOB CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(col_2, '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d*$'))
    )
LOB (col_2) STORE AS SECUREFILE (TABLESPACE TABLESPACE_A DISABLE STORAGE IN ROW)
TABLESPACE TABLESPACE_B;

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (col_1, col_2) 
   VALUES (SYSDATE,TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));
```

Again, `col_1` would be stored in a different segment than `col_2`.

But clear statement: I don't recommend to use any of these workarounds!